# Get TFS Difference files in a project Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs

Recently, It happened that a Project was replaced in a solution from Windows Explorer. when we reopen the solution in Visual studio it prompted for reload of the modified project but can't see what files in those project are different from TFS Copy (a red check mark indicating file checkout/modified was missing).

Is there any way that we can compare the files that were actually different from TFS Copy for this specific project?

Comment: do  you have `NotePad++` use that to open the .proj file and do a comparison

Answer (score 2):

TFS is a source repository, hence it keeps track of all changes made over time.

All you need to do is as follows:

- Open the TFS Solution in the TFS Source Control Explorer
- Identify the Project directory from within the Source Control explorer
- Right click on the project directory in the Source Control explorer
- Select the menu option View History
- Now from there, select any changeset (set of changes at a point in time) and compare that with either a previous change set or your local changes
- Note: in order to compare a specific changeset with your local copy, you need to right click on a changeset and select the "Compare" menu option to compare
- Note: in order to compare the differences between two changesets, you need to select the two changesets, right click on it and select the "Compare" menu option